# Category Import with Magento 1.6.1; how to set on default category

Tags: magento

My problem is that after an import of products, the product is not shown on the frontend.

Reason: The default category for the products are not marked. If I do this manually, I can see the product on the frontend.

How can I tell the products during the import that the default category must be marked?

I am talking about Magento 1.6.1 which is different to older Magento versions with the import of categories. As far as I have found out, it is no longer possible to import Category IDs, so I have to import the name of the category.

I have an import mistake for that:
`_category` (this is one of the column titles of my csv sheet for importing)
`Default Category/Firmen/Levis` (for example)

it is not working, but

if I just take:

```
_category
Firmen
```

then it works

Any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do first is to export and see format of generatrd cvs file. This way you could reformat your import file.
Sometimes I had to do my custom import php script, you may have to do the same if this solution doesn't meet your requirements.